# How to combine rows in Database if the repeat checking on two columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datatable

I want to update my `DataTable` and combine the rows where username and server name repeat.

I want to keep all the rows the same, just combine the `LearningGroups` Column.

Kindly see image attached for better understanding:
[image]

As you can see the first two rows are the same, so i want them to make it 1 with learning groups added.

I have seen many example here but i cannot change it to my needs because i need to filter using two columns  `ServeName,Username`  and concatinate string column LearningGroup.

Any help highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

FOUND A POSSIBLE SOLUTION HERE:

```
  var result = report.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(r => new
        {
            Version = r.Field<String>("f_username"),
            Col1 = r.Field<String>("servername"),

        })
        .Select(g =>
        {
            var row = g.First();
         //   row.SetField("LearningGroupName", g.Concat(r => r.Field<string>("LearningGroupName"))); 
            return row;
        }).CopyToDataTable();
```

But it returns the new one with the first LearningGroupName row which is empty as i have commented this line, its giving error it was to add column values so not sure how do i change it to concatinate?

Comment: what is the code you are using to retrieve the data?

Comment: @TI That is a long query with Joins between 4 tables so i dont want to mess with that i want to do it after i have the Database as above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this manually by looping through each DataRow of the DataTable and check the previous row and decide whether to add the row to the new dataTable like or merge.

```
DataTable _newTable = new DataTable();

foreach(DataRow _row in _dataTable) {

}
```

or change the underlying data to fix the issue or do this using SQL. I would do it in C# or fix the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Simple class:

```
class Foo
{
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string LearningGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Initialization of sample data:

```
List<Foo> _source = new List<Foo> 
        {
            new Foo { ServerName ="ServA", UserName = "John", LearningGroup ="First Group" },
            new Foo { ServerName ="ServA", UserName = "Kate", LearningGroup ="First Group" },
            new Foo { ServerName ="ServA", UserName = "John" },
            new Foo { ServerName ="ServB", UserName = "Kate", },
            new Foo { ServerName ="ServB", UserName = "Kate", LearningGroup ="Second Group" }
        };
```

Query to resolve the problem:

```
var tmp = (from x in _source
          join f in _source on new { UserName = x.UserName, ServerName = x.ServerName } equals new { UserName = f.UserName, ServerName = f.ServerName }
          where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.LearningGroup)                      
          select x).Distinct();
```

**DataTable solution:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ServerName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("LearningGroup", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("ServA", "John", "First Group");
dt.Rows.Add("ServA", "Kate", "First Group");
dt.Rows.Add("ServA", "John", null);
dt.Rows.Add("ServB", "Kate", null);
dt.Rows.Add("ServB", "Kate", "Second Group");

var tmpDT = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
             join f in dt.AsEnumerable() on new { UserName = x.Field<String>("UserName"), ServerName = x.Field<String>("ServerName") } equals new { UserName = f.Field<String>("UserName"), ServerName = f.Field<String>("ServerName") }
             where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<String>("LearningGroup"))
             select x).Distinct();
```

Result type of this query is `IEnumerable<DataRow>` so you can use foreach loop to create new `DataTable` with appropriate data:

```
DataTable newDT = new DataTable();
newDT.Columns.Add("ServerName", typeof(string));
newDT.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
newDT.Columns.Add("LearningGroup", typeof(string));

foreach (var item in tmpDT)
{
    newDT.ImportRow(item);
}
```

Comment: I am using DataTable can the above be modified to deal with that?

Comment: @confusedMind check my answer again :)

Comment: Thank you but i am finding it a bit difficult to implement so i might try the simple idea posted by iefpw.

Comment: How do i covert the tmpDT back to DataTable ? :|

Comment: @confusedMind check my answer one more time:)

Comment: Sorry buddy its still giving exception on line foreach.... i might have to drop this.

Comment: @confusedMind what exception you have?

Comment: @confusedMind do you remember this exception? I'm curious why this solution doesn't work for you:)

Comment: sorry i replaced the code and dont remember but it was not allowing  it to read. Exception was on 
 foreach (var item in tmpDT)
{
    newDT.ImportRow(item);
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you're required output is, but presumably you want to group duplicate pupils and concatenate their courses and tutors

A full working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // setup dummy DataTable
        var tbl = new DataTable();

        tbl.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
        tbl.Columns.Add("learningGroup", typeof(String));
        tbl.Columns.Add("tutor", typeof(String));

        tbl.Rows.Add(1, "", "");
        tbl.Rows.Add(1, "group 1", "sam");
        tbl.Rows.Add(2, "group 1", "john");
        tbl.Rows.Add(3, "group 2", "paul");

        tbl = Group(tbl);

        // print DataTable
        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                Console.Write(item+"|");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    // Group-Concat learningGroup and 
    // tutor copying to new DataTable
    static DataTable Group(DataTable tbl)
    {
        var groups = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(r => r.Field<Int32>("id"))
                        .Select(g => new {
                                            id = g.Key,
                                            learningGroup = string.Join(",", g.Select(s => s["learningGroup"])).TrimStart(','),
                                            tutor = string.Join(",", g.Select(s => s["tutor"])).TrimStart(','),
                                         });

        var newtbl = new DataTable();

        newtbl.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
        newtbl.Columns.Add("learningGroup", typeof(String));
        newtbl.Columns.Add("tutor", typeof(String));

        foreach (var g in groups)
        {
            newtbl.Rows.Add(g.id, g.learningGroup, g.tutor);
        }

        return newtbl;
    }
}
```